# Pandas: using str.contains and map to find some substring and replace value in column

Tags: python, pandas

I have dataframe

```
member_id,device_type,device_id,event_type,event_path,event_duration
603609,url,mail.ru/,0,pc,7d4a095373874b4fb26a2e6d070b6ad3
603609,url,mail.ru/,0,pc,7d4a095373874b4fb26a2e6d070b6ad3
603609,url,mail.ru/,0,pc,7d4a095373874b4fb26a2e6d070b6ad3
603609,url,mail.ru/,3,pc,7d4a095373874b4fb26a2e6d070b6ad3
603609,url,mail.ru/community.livejournal.com/psp_ru,28,pc,7d4a095373874b4fb26a2e6d070b6ad3
603609,url,lady.mail.ru/article/491411-kurban-omarov-otvetil-na-obvinenija-ksenii-borodinoj/?from=mr_news,0,pc,7d4a095373874b4fb26a2e6d070b6ad3
603609,url,mail.ru/,0,pc,7d4a095373874b4fb26a2e6d070b6ad3
603609,url,lady.mail.ru/article/491411-kurban-omarov-otvetil-na-obvinenija-ksenii-borodinoj/?from=mr_news,0,pc,7d4a095373874b4fb26a2e6d070b6ad3
603609,url,lady.mail.ru/article/491411-kurban-omarov-otvetil-na-obvinenija-ksenii-borodinoj/?from=mr_news,0,pc,7d4a095373874b4fb26a2e6d070b6ad3
```

And I should find substring from another file and if it contain pattrn, create a column `category` from df2

```
url category    category2
falloutsite.ru/ Рубрики/Hi-Tech/Программы/Софт/Игры/    Рубрики/Hi-Tech/Программы/Софт/Игры/ 
kmzpub.ru/games.asp Рубрики/Hi-Tech/Программы/Софт/Игры/Универсальное/  Рубрики/Hi-Tech/Программы/Софт/Игры/Универсальное/ 
sigma-team.ru/content/view/15/19    Рубрики/Hi-Tech/Программы/Софт/Игры/Quake и Counter-Strike/     Рубрики/Hi-Tech/Программы/Софт/Игры/Quake и Counter-Strike/ 
community.livejournal.com/psp_ru    Рубрики/Развлечения/Игры/Приставочные игры/     Рубрики/Развлечения/Игры/Приставочные игры/
```

I use

```
df = df1[df1['device_id'].str.contains('|'.join(find_urls))]
```

to find substring, but how can I replace that.
I usually use `map`, but in this case strings should be common

Comment: What is `find_urls` ?

Comment: @jezrael it's list of url from df2 `df2.url.values.tolist()`

Comment: Hmm, what is size of `len(df2)` ?

Comment: Is df = df1[df1['device_id'].isin(find_urls)] what you're looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible solution:

```
#create dict for map
d = df2.set_index('url')['category'].to_dict()
print (d)
{'community.livejournal.com/psp_ru': 'Рубрики/Развлечения/Игры/Приставочныеигры/',
 'kmzpub.ru/games.asp': 'Рубрики/Hi-Tech/Программы/Софт/Игры/Универсальное/Рубрики/Hi-Tech/Программы/Софт/Игры/Универсальное/', 
 'falloutsite.ru/': 'Рубрики/Hi-Tech/Программы/Софт/Игры/', 
 'sigma-team.ru/content/view/15/19': 'Рубрики/Hi-Tech/Программы/Софт/Игры/QuakeиCounter-Strike/'}

#use list comprehension for map by substring   
print (df1.device_id.apply(lambda x: pd.Series([v for k,v in d.items() if k in x])) )
                                            0
0                                         NaN
1                                         NaN
2                                         NaN
3                                         NaN
4  Рубрики/Развлечения/Игры/Приставочныеигры/
5                                         NaN
6                                         NaN
7                                         NaN
8                                         NaN
```

---

```
df1['category']=df1.device_id.apply(lambda x: pd.Series([v for k,v in d.items() if k in x])) 
print (df1)
   member_id device_type                                          device_id  \
0     603609         url                                           mail.ru/   
1     603609         url                                           mail.ru/   
2     603609         url                                           mail.ru/   
3     603609         url                                           mail.ru/   
4     603609         url           mail.ru/community.livejournal.com/psp_ru   
5     603609         url  lady.mail.ru/article/491411-kurban-omarov-otve...   
6     603609         url                                           mail.ru/   
7     603609         url  lady.mail.ru/article/491411-kurban-omarov-otve...   
8     603609         url  lady.mail.ru/article/491411-kurban-omarov-otve...   

   event_type event_path                    event_duration  \
0           0         pc  7d4a095373874b4fb26a2e6d070b6ad3   
1           0         pc  7d4a095373874b4fb26a2e6d070b6ad3   
2           0         pc  7d4a095373874b4fb26a2e6d070b6ad3   
3           3         pc  7d4a095373874b4fb26a2e6d070b6ad3   
4          28         pc  7d4a095373874b4fb26a2e6d070b6ad3   
5           0         pc  7d4a095373874b4fb26a2e6d070b6ad3   
6           0         pc  7d4a095373874b4fb26a2e6d070b6ad3   
7           0         pc  7d4a095373874b4fb26a2e6d070b6ad3   
8           0         pc  7d4a095373874b4fb26a2e6d070b6ad3   

                                     category  
0                                         NaN  
1                                         NaN  
2                                         NaN  
3                                         NaN  
4  Рубрики/Развлечения/Игры/Приставочныеигры/  
5                                         NaN  
6                                         NaN  
7                                         NaN  
8                                         NaN
```

---

EDIT by comment:

It seems there is no match by dict, you can test it by sample:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'device_id':['a d','b s','c r'], 'b':[1,2,3]})    
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'url':['a','m','k'], 'category':['one','two','three']})    
#df2 = pd.DataFrame({'url':['a r','m','k'], 'category':['one','two','three']})    


d = df2.set_index('url')['category'].to_dict()
print (d)
{'k': 'three', 'a': 'one', 'm': 'two'}

df1['category']=df1.device_id.apply(lambda x: pd.Series([v for k,v in d.items() if k in x])) 
print (df1)
   b device_id category
0  1       a d      one
1  2       b s      NaN
2  3       c r      NaN
```

Comment: `df3 = df1.url.str.extract(pat, expand=True)` returns `AssertionError: sorry, but this version only supports 100 named groups`. I tried to use `df = df1[df1['device_id'].str.contains('|'.join(find_urls))]` and next `print (pd.merge(df, df2[['url','category']], how='left', on='url'))`, but column with category is empty

Comment: first it return the warning `sys:1: DtypeWarning: Columns (0,3) have mixed types. Specify dtype option on import or set low_memory=False.` and next error `ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 0, placement implies 1`

Comment: You can test it by uncommented `df2`

Comment: yes. I use `find_urls = find.url.values.tolist()
df1 = df[df['device_id'].str.contains('|'.join(find_urls))]` to make dataframe little. but it returns `ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 2, placement implies 1`.

Comment: it is really hard help you withiout your data. But if data are not confidental, please send me both csv to my email in my profile and I try found problem.

Comment: I think blue.xlsx and car owners games_category.csv

Comment: jozefeg@gmail.com?

Comment: exactly, this is my email:)

Comment: send you a message)

Comment: did you get my email?